# Do JavaFX beans need to be serializable?

Tags: javafx

Many [JavaFX constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleStringProperty.html#SimpleStringProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), such as for [`SimpleStringProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleStringProperty.html) specify that the first argument should be a bean. I know that one of the qualities of JavaBeans is that they are `Serializable`. The sample code in [The Definitive Guide to Modern Java Clients with JavaFX](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484249253), has [examples](https://github.com/Apress/definitive-guide-modern-java-clients-javafx/blob/3766db59dae84f2753dcdfea1271755dde7ee030/ch02-javafx%20fundamentals/personui/src/main/java/com/modernclient/model/Person.java#L12) where the parameter passed in the bean position is not serializable:

```java
public class Person { // not Serializable
    private final StringProperty firstname = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "fistname", "");
    private final StringProperty lastname = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastname", "");
    private final StringProperty notes = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "notes", "sample notes");
```

Are JavaFX beans required to be `Serializable` or only to have a public no-args constructor and setters/getters to access private fields?

Comment: Making a class that uses JavaFX properties serializable is not a simple matter of implementing `Serializable` because the JavaFX properties themselves are not serializable. It appears JavaFX decided to forgo that "requirement" of beans since serializing UI objects is questionable at best. If you notice, very few—if any at all—of the classes in the core JavaFX libraries are serializable.

Comment: Thanks, @Slaw. I understand that adding `implements Serializable` is not sufficient (but is necessary) for a class to be serializable. If you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: JavaBean != bean-field-of-property :) They have nothing in common, except containing "bean" ..

Comment: @kleopatra I would _assume_ they named [that property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyProperty.html#getBean()) of `ReadOnlyProperty` "bean" with the intention of relating it to JavaBean. The property's owning object is at least similar to a JavaBean (though notably typically not serializable, and you add the listeners to the properties themselves rather than the bean).

Comment: @Slaw assumptions about dev intentions are .. <g> And I tend to disagree with _property's owning object is at least similar_ - that similarity holds only for and immediately ends at naming conventions. The really important difference is who is in control: in fx the owning object has no control whatever about the firing of the notification, whereas a JavaBean is bound by contract as to when/if to fire (namely, _must not_ fire any change until its state is completely updated).

Comment: @kleopatra The reason I have that assumption is I'm pretty sure I've read official documentation mention the "JavaFXBean" which was an "extension of JavaBean", where the "extension" was the addition of the so-called property-getters. But I don't remember where I read that, or when.

Comment: @kleopatra Could you make that an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not not mandatory for a Class to be `Serializable` unless you intend to use serialization on that Class or any Subclass

Comment: I understand that. The question is what is meant by a JavaFX bean.